# How to catch an error when relinking a table linked fails in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling

I have some code in a class that relinks a bunch of vba tables, but some of them are coming back as never having relinked dispite a lack of errors:

```
Function relinkTable(ByVal theTbl As String, ByVal newPath As String)
    Dim oCat As Object
    Set oCat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    Set oCat.ActiveConnection = cn

    ' http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230588
    For Each tbl In oCat.Tables


        If tbl.Type = "LINK" And StrComp(theTbl, tbl.Name) = 0 Then

            'Debug.Print "------------------"
            'Debug.Print "Name: " & tbl.Name
            'Debug.Print "Type: " & tbl.Type
            'Debug.Print "Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource:" & tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource")
            'Debug.Print "Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name:" & tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name")
            'Debug.Print "Jet OLEDB:Create Link: " & tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link")

            ' This is sometimes not occurring:
            tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource") = newPath 

            Exit For
        End If
    Next tbl

    Set oCat = Nothing
End Function
```

Is there a way to catch an error when this fails?

Comment: I would go to the navigation column and use Linked Table Manager for the ones that don't work.

Comment: Why are you using adox rather than dao? Access works best with dao, which is the most up-to-date connection.

Comment: Could you not trap the error with an Error Handler?